# Broadcast receivers in background when app is not in recents

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to create an Application which *toasts* the battery level **whenever** the battery level changes. I am using Broadcast receiver and which is registered with 'ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED'. It works fine in the background only when the app is still in the recents (i.e. the app is not closed), but it **doesn't work when the app is closed**!

['ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED' is fired when the BatteryLevel changes.]

Below is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //registering the reciever.
    this.registerReceiver(this.mBatInfoReciever,new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));

}
private BroadcastReceiver mBatInfoReciever = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        int level = intent.getIntExtra("level",0);
        /*To get the Battery Level.*/

        Toast t=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),String.valueOf(level),Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        t.show();

    }

};


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once your `MainActivity` is destroyed, your `BroadcastReceiver` goes away. This will occur:

- If the user presses BACK, or
- If the user navigates away by some other means (e.g., presses HOME) and your process is terminated

You seem to be defining "the app is closed" as being when the user swipes the app out of the overview screen (recent task list). That usually terminates the app's process, so your `BroadcastReceiver` will be gone at that point.

Comment: By saying that "the app is closed" , I mean that the app is not running in the background . It  works fine if i started the app and i press the home button (example : say I press home and start some other app , it still toasts the Battery level) ; but once I remove the app from the recents it doesn't work .  Please guide what should be done so that it can run even when the app is closed.

Comment: @PremBharwani: "I mean that the app is not running in the background" -- that would mean that your process is terminated. Your `BroadcastReceiver` is gone at that point.

Comment: Okay , but why is my BroadcastReciever gone ? I haven't created it in the OnCreate() method of the Class . So what are the methods through which I can achieve this when the app is closed? Thank You . @CommonsWare

Comment: @PremBharwani: "but why is my BroadcastReciever gone ?" -- when your process is terminated, everything of your app in memory is gone. "So what are the methods through which I can achieve this when the app is closed?" -- generally, you don't. That broadcast is for running apps that might want to change behavior based on battery level changes. As of Android 8.0, most system broadcasts behave that way: they are only delivered to running apps. You could try to use a foreground service and have your `BroadcastReceiver` to try to keep your process running longer.

Comment: I completely understood ! Thanks a LOT ! ( I can't Upvote , I am sorry for that )